# Android: Get photo path after capturing photo from camera throw cameraIntent

Tags: android, image, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I am using camera Intent to open the camera:

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

Now I am trying to get the path of the captured photo but its throwing error:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
Uri uri = data.getData();
String imagePath = getRealPathFromURI(uri);
}
}

private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
// import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader; i import this for CursorLoader
    CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(getApplicationContext(), contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    Cursor cursor = loader.loadInBackground();
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

Its throwing Error which is:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=100,     result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity  {com.xxx.xxx.BbmpActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2536)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2578)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:965)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)  
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)    
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)     
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException   
at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireProvider(ContentResolver.java:743)    
at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:256)
at android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:49)
at com.pixel.bbmp.BbmpActivity.getRealPathFromURI2(BbmpActivity.java:546)
at com.pixel.bbmp.BbmpActivity.onActivityResult(BbmpActivity.java:491)  
at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3908)  
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2532)
```

I think because of this line it throwing error:

```
CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(getApplicationContext(), contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
```

here what i need to give instead of getApplicationContext()
I also try this but till it throwing error:

```
CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(this, contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
```

when I start this application then it throw one error which is:

```
Could not find class 'android.content.CursorLoader', referenced from method com.xxx.xxx.BbmpActivity.getRealPathFromURI
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Uri uri = data.getData();`write like..

```
if(data!=null){
  if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {  
           Uri uri =  data.getExtras().get("data"); 
         //or...
     Bitmap bitmapPicture = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
     // other code
}
}
```

It will work fine. main thing is `data.getExtras().get("data");`

Comment: its showing error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to Uri for Uri uri =  data.getExtras().get("data"); And if I write Bitmap bitmapPicture = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); then how i send uri as an argument to getRealPathFromURI method

Comment: u can compress the bitmap and then send it to the stream in byte form

Comment: my problem is how I get the path. Uri uri =  data.getExtras().get("data"); this line throwing error. which is Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to Uri

Comment: for the line: Uri uri =  data.getExtras().get("data");  In the logcat it throwing error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=100, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {com.xxx.xxx/com.xxx.xxx.BbmpActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.Bit

Comment: The intent data object passed as parm to onActivityResult() can be null, even though the camera took the picture and saved it to storage. It's a PITA.  There are numerious posts about this, including at least one bug report to Google/Android as some people (like me) consider this a bug, not an oversight.  You would (and should) expect the camera to tell you where to find that photo you just took, otherwise how could you even use it? Pretty lame.

Answer (score 0):

```
CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(getApplicationContext(), 
MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
proj, null, null, null);
```

Comment: @HowardPautz: have you got an idea why the original question was deleted?

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember what it said about the link that was dead - was just cleaning up. I came across this because of Samsung devices not reading files from /storage/sdcard0 ...

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a URI before when setup the capture intent :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(this.mCameraFile));
startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Where mCameraFile is a file I created :

```
this.mCameraFile = File.createTempFile("toto", "jpg", fAlbum);
```

Where fAlbum, is a File that represent my album folder :

```
this.fAlbum = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/dcim/" + "tata";
```